# How to solve analytically this equation?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

I need to solve the next equation and to find $x_1$:

$$\dfrac{d(x_0x_1)}{dz}=-\beta\dfrac{dx_0}{dz}\dfrac{1}{r-z(r-1)}$$

where $x_0$, $x_1$, $z$ are variables, and $r$, $\beta$ are constants.

At this point is it possible to multiply whole equation with $dz$, will I lose some information because of the therm $\dfrac{1}{r-z(r-1)}$?

On the other side, I have expression for $x_0=f(z)$, it is dependent on $z$:

$x_0=\left(1+\dfrac{\beta}{r-1}\left(  1-\dfrac{1}{(r-z(r-1))^3} \right)\right)^{0.5}$

On which side I need to go to integrate this equation?

Comment: Your notation isn't very clear. Is $x_1$ a constant, or a variable? If it is a variable, then $d(x_0x_1)/dz = x_1\,dx_0/dz + x_0\, dx_1/dz$ using the chain rule...

Comment: I edited question and added information after the first equation.

Comment: What is causing you to think that you need to pick a side? What do you want for your final expression? For example, are you after $x_o(x_1, z)$ or $x_1(x_o, z)$ or $z(x_o, x_1)$? By analogy, with a projectile over a plane, we typically want to find its height $z$ as a function of its location $x, y$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\alpha := r - 1$.  Then, the original equation can be written as 
$$
 (1) \quad \dfrac{dx_1}{dz} = \left[x_1+\dfrac{\beta}{r-\alpha z}\right]\left[-\dfrac{1}{x_0}\dfrac{dx_0}{dz}\right]
$$
where
$$
 (2) \quad x_0^2 = \left[1 + \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}\right] -\left[\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}\dfrac{1}{(r-\alpha z)^3} \right]
$$
We want to find $x_1$ analytically by solving (1).

Differentiation of (2) gives
$$
 (3) \quad \dfrac{dx_0}{dz} = -\dfrac{1}{2x_0}\dfrac{3\beta}{(r-\alpha z)^4}
$$
Therefore, the last factor in (1) can be written as
$$
 (4) \quad -\dfrac{1}{x_0} \dfrac{dx_0}{dz} = \dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{\beta^2}{x_0^2(r-\alpha z)^4}
$$
Now, using (2),
$$
  \begin{align}
  \frac{x_0^2(r-\alpha z)^4}{\beta^2}  & = \frac{1}{\beta^2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)(r-\alpha z)^4 - \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}(r-\alpha z) \\
  & = \dfrac{r-\alpha z}{\alpha\beta^2} \left[\left(\alpha + \beta\right)(r-\alpha z)^3 - \beta\right]
  \end{align}
$$
We can now write (4) as
$$
(5) \quad -\dfrac{1}{x_0} \dfrac{dx_0}{dz} = \left(\dfrac{3\alpha\beta}{2}\right) \left(\dfrac{\beta}{r-\alpha z}\right) \left[\dfrac{1}{\left(\alpha + \beta\right)(r-\alpha z)^3 - \beta}\right]
$$
Plug (5) into (1) to get
$$
(6) \quad \dfrac{dx_1}{dz} = \dfrac{3\alpha\beta}{2}\left[x_1+\dfrac{\beta}{r-\alpha z}\right] \left(\dfrac{\beta}{r-\alpha z}\right) \left[\dfrac{1}{\left(\alpha + \beta\right)(r-\alpha z)^3 - \beta}\right]
$$
Do a change of variables by defining $y := r - \alpha z$.  Then
$$
  \frac{dx_1}{dz} = \frac{dx_1}{dy} \dfrac{dy}{dz} = -\alpha \frac{dx_1}{dy}
$$
We can now write (6) as
$$
(7) \quad \dfrac{dx_1}{dy} = -\dfrac{3\beta}{2}\left[x_1+\dfrac{\beta}{y}\right] \left[\dfrac{\beta}{\left(\alpha + \beta\right)y^4 - \beta y}\right]
$$
or
$$
(8) \quad \dfrac{dx_1}{dy} = -\dfrac{3\beta^2}{2}\left[\dfrac{ x_1}{\left(\alpha + \beta\right)y^4 - \beta y} +  \dfrac{\beta}{\left(\alpha + \beta\right)y^5 - \beta y^2}\right]
$$
You can now solve the ODE using standard approaches, e.g., http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx.  The solution is a complex mix of square roots, logs, and arctans.

Comment: I have tried to extract terms $x_1$ and $\dfrac{1}{y}$ from the terms in squared brackets, and then integrate but it doens't work, because there always stay some of these terms? Do you have some other advice, that is only what I understood from the link?

Comment: The ODE is of the form $ dx/dy + a(y) x + b(y) = 0$. Because you may be unfamiliar (or have forgotten)  with solving ordinary differential equations,  I would suggest you study the approaches explained in the link in my answer.  The analytical solution requires a large number of steps.